# How to use strnlen safely?

Tags: c, strlen

I am trying to understand what is the correct way to use `strnlen` so that it will be used safely even considering edge cases.

Like for example having a non null-terminated string as input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    void* data = malloc(5);

    size_t len = strnlen((const char*)data, 10);
    printf("len = %zu\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

If I expect a string of max size `10`, but the string does not contain the null character within those 10 characters `strnlen` will read out of bounds bytes (the input pointer may point to heap allocated data). Is this behavior undefined? If yes, is there a way to safely use `strnlen` to compute the length of a string which takes into account this type of scenario and does not lead to undefined behavior?

Comment: How do you define your string's length when it's not NUL-terminated?

Comment: To use `strnlen()`, the second argument needs to specify an upper limit of length.   In your case, the call of `strnlen()` should not have a second argument exceeding `5`.   If you don't respect that, you will cause undefined behaviour, and there is no way around that.

Comment: The question is how to use `strnlen` and is tagged with C, not how to avoid `strnlen` and ditch C.

Comment: The C-safe approach may be `strnlen` or `memchr`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use `strnlen` safely you need to

1. Keep track of the size of the input buffer yourself (5 in your case) and pass *that* as the second parameter, *not* a number greater than that.
2. Make sure the input pointer is not `NULL`.
3. Make sure another thread is not writing to the buffer.

Formally, you don't need to initialise the contents of the buffer, as conceptually the function reads the buffer as if they are `char` types.

Answer (score 1):

This code will most likely invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The bytes returned by `malloc` have indeterminate values.  If there are no null bytes in the 5 bytes that are returned, then `strnlen` will read past those bytes since it was passed a max of 10, and reading past the end of allocated memory invokes undefined behavior.

Simply reading the bytes that were returned however should *not* be undefined.  While indeterminate values could hold a trap representation,  `strnlen` reads the bytes using a `char *`, and character types do *not* have trap representation, so the values are merely unspecified and reading them is safe.

If the value passed to `strnlen` is no larger than the size of allocated memory, then its usage is safe.

Comment: Not so fast. The behaviour of reading uninitialised bytes `char` by `char` is not undefined. But indeed reading beyond the buffer *is* undefined.

Comment: @Bathsheba True in theory, very much _not_ true in practice; every compiler I have tested takes J.2 "The behavior is undefined if ... a value [of any type whatsoever, whether or not it has trap representations] is used while it is indeterminate" as normative, even though a close reading of the actual text does not go that far.

Comment: In this case it is undefined as the allocated block is 5 bytes and the `strnlen` max len is `10`, therefore, that is a problem. Else if the `maxlen` is less than or equal to the allocated memory block length, then it should be fine.

Comment: @Bathsheba: You are correct: " You're reading uninitialized bytes, " part is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual length of data is 5 and you most likely don't have a '\0' in there, it will start reading unallocated memory(starting at data[5]), which might be a little unpleasant.

Comment: You've almost answered the first part of the question (*Is this behavior undefined?*), but not the main question (*What's the correct way to use `strnlen()`?*).  So this doesn't really qualify as an answer, I'm afraid.